# apt-get remove not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 install and need to remove cuda 9.0 so that I can install cuda 8.0. I have tried several commands like

sudo apt-get remove --purge cuda
sudo apt-get remove --purge cuda*
sudo apt-get remove --purge cuda-9-0

None of them work. Does anyone have any further suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't really an on-topic question for [SO]. In future somewhere like askubuntu would be more suitable

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove "^cuda.*"
```

This will remove cuda and all associated dependencies, and then you can install cuda version that you want.